# RatingBar deforms my layout in Android 2.3

Tags: android, layout, ratingbar

This is how an item of my ListView in my app looks in Android 4.4 (real device):

[image]

And this is how the same activity in the same app looks in Android 2.3 (real device, too):

[image]

As you can see, I am using a custom layout for the rating bar, which deforms the activity in Android 2.3 with this horrible vertical bars. Can someone tell me why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set correct `android:minHeight` and `android:maxHeight` values for your stars style. This happens because of different parent styles on different platforms.